# How to select part of a Timestamp in a SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, distinct, extract

In the DB I am working with, I want to select only the year from a specific TimeStamp field.  In particular, I'm hoping to select the unique years from this database column.

For instance, if all of the timestamps in the field `"ModifyTimeStamp"` are either from the year 2002 or the year 2006, I would like returned simply a result of '2002' and '2006'.  If this is impossible, I'd be content with getting a result of a bunch of '2002's mixed with '2006's and would parse it later.

All I've been able to get working so far is `"Select ModifyTimeStamp from Table"` - all my attempts to parse have failed.  I started reading about the `extract` command for SQL, but I believe it's only for PostgreSQL.

Any advice greatly appreciated!

**Edit**: Got the answer, thanks a lot datagod and Marc.  The code I was looking for ended up being:

`"Select distinct YEAR(ModifyTimeStamp) from Table"`

Comment: Which database? (Also, random information: `timestamp` in SQL server has nothing to do with dates or times ;-)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to specify.  MySQL database

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't specify which RDBMS (database server) you're using, but most databases do have date handling functions built-in:

- MySQL/SQL Server:

  ```
  select YEAR(modifytimestamp) from yourtable
  ```
- Access/SQL Server:

  ```
  select DatePart(year, modifytimestamp) from yourtable
  ```
- Oracle:

  ```
  select TO_CHAR(modifytimestamp, 'YYYY') from yourtable
  ```

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
select distinct datepart(yy,TheDate) from YourTable
```

Comment: This works for MS SQL Server, but other RDBMSs will have similar function calls.

Comment: Reference: [SQL Server (2008) datepart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

Comment: Thanks datagod.  My actual command ended up being a little different, but you put me on the right track with the "distinct" keyword.  Can't believe I missed that in my search...