# I am trying to select only the year portion of a timestamp in my sql query

Tags: sql

I am trying to select only the year portion of a timestamp in my sql query.  Data is in this format:

```
2016-12-13 23:59:58
2016-12-07 23:59:58
2016-12-01 23:59:58
```

I wanted my query results to only return "2016" for example.

Comment: What dbms are you using? Have you tried searching? This is fairly easy to accomplish.

Comment: In standard SQL this would be `extract(year from the_column)`

Comment: SQL Server would be either `Year(YourColumn)` or `DatePart(Year, YourColumn)`.  Again, this is very easily found on Google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select part of a Timestamp in a SQL Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808732/how-to-select-part-of-a-timestamp-in-a-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

If SQL Server, do

```
SELECT DATEPART(year,'2016-12-13 23:59:58')
```

and you will get 2016. If some other RDBMS, probably something similar.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres there is date_part function the does this job. the first argument is the part that needs to be extracted and second argument is the time stamp:

example:
`select date_part('year', timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40');`

for further details: [postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-datetime.html)

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Server**

If you are having trouble, make sure your column is actually a timestamp and not just a string:

```
SELECT 
DATEPART(YEAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-12-13 23:59:58')) as YR
FROM TABLENAME
```

In your actual query, you would want to replace `'2016-12-13 23:59:58'` with the column name.

```
SELECT 
DATEPART(YEAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, DateColumn)) as YR
FROM TABLENAME
```

**Oracle**

```
SELECT 
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (TO_DATE('2016-12-13 23:59:58', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') )) as YR
FROM TABLENAME
```

Similarly

```
SELECT 
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (TO_DATE(DateColumn, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') )) as YR
FROM TABLENAME
```